# To keep iOS App running in background using any of the background modes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-task

I have an iOS App that needs to be run in background for finite amount of time.I have tried with all the background methods like VoIP,

location update,beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler etc.mention in https://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios ,

Using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler i am able to run the app in background but the problem is when i hit localhost URL from safari there are certain C functions which needs to be called from the App but safari takes too long or some sometimes shows cannot connect to server.

But if i launch localhost from safari and navigate back to app the functions are called and localhost is launched in safari.

I need to be able to call this method even in background.

This app won't be published in Store so apple's rejection is not an issue. Please help.